# How do I unblock a port on an amazon ec2 server while the virtual machine is running

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, port, torrent

I'm trying to set up a headless torrent server on my amazon ec2 server. I have also added port `9091` to the list of enabled ports but can't access it over the internet.

This is the [url](http://ec2-204-236-198-119.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9091/transmission) for my server. I can access this if I use links2.
My server is a 32bit ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine.

I tried to check if ufw was in use but the status for that is inactive.
How can I unblock the port and access it remotely?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow this port in the security group for the ec2 server in order to get access to it. You can find more info at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Answer (score 0):

This will be done using UFW (a friendly interface for iptables),

To enable access to a given port with UFW:

```
ufw allow proto tcp from any to 9091
```

The only thing is I seem to remember older EC2 instances didn't support UFW, so to add it directly to iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9091 -j ACCEPT
```